# Sap Hybris advanced search label configuration

Tags: java, xml, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I wonder if is it possible change label of an field (Time created)in advanced search and how I do it.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is not programming related, right?

Answer (score 0):

Update this properties in your Backoffice extension:

```
hmc.creationtime=Creation time
```

Comment: Please do not include 'fluff' in your posts, such as 'hi' or 'thank you' or 'please', etc. Remind also to use code formatting for code

Answer (score 0):

**creationTime** attribute is created under abstract type **Item**.

To change the label, have the below property in core extension *project.properties*
and refresh BackOffice

```
type.item.creationtime.name=Time created
```